# how to make a sharepoint restful call from node

Tags: node.js, authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm new in node and I want to connect between sharepoint 2013 (on demand) and node.
I want to get list of items from sharepoint website.
Our users using smart cards to connect to our system (Active directory users) so I can't get their password.

I want to know if there is a way to connect sharepoint with node and what is the best way to do so.

Example of http call : `http.get(http://servername/portal/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('dsfd')/items)`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [pnp/js](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/) because is specifically developed for SharePoint request and you can install it via `npm i` and use it easily.

If you don't want use `pnp/js` you can always launch manually a REST API request thank to `fetch` (doesn't work on IE) or [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).